# How to pass imploded values in NOT IN condition in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

When I try to  `print_r($temp); exit();` I am getting below values in comma separated form
`805,806`

But when I am passing this values in MY, not in condition then it only works for `806` not for both `805` and `806`.

below is my code...

```
public function newOrderList() { 
    if($this->processRequest){
            $conditio = array('User.id'=>$this->requestData['courierId'],'User.user_type'=>2); 
            $checkUser = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>$conditio));
            if(!empty($checkUser)){
                $courierId = $this->requestData['courierId'];
                $cond = array('OrderRejectedDetail.courier_id'=>$courierId); 
                $ordRej = $this->OrderRejectedDetail->find('all',array('conditions'=>$cond));
                if(!empty($ordRej)){
                    foreach ($ordRej as $key => $value) {
                        $orderId[] = $value['OrderRejectedDetail']['order_id'];
                    }
                    $temp = implode(',',$orderId);
                }                  
                $data = $this->Order->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        "NOT" => array("Order.id" => array($temp))
                    )
                ));
                print_r($data); exit();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: "Order.id" => explode(",", $temp)

Comment: you need to pass it like this : `NOT IN ('805','806')`

Comment: Why do you need to implode in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need implode any more, make your code something like this:

```
if(!empty($ordRej)){
    foreach ($ordRej as $key => $value) {
        $orderId[] = $value['OrderRejectedDetail']['order_id'];
    }
    // $temp = implode(',', $orderId);
}                  
$data = $this->Order->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array('Order.id' => $orderId)
    )
));
```